# Working example of running a test using proboscis

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have created a `first.py` file with the following code in it. And then ran it as python `first.py` from command prompt (or) from Pycharm by right clicking on `first.py` and hitting run button. And i see the following output.

I expected the `test1()` function to run and pass. Why is my test not running?

## Output:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe
C:/Users/sbulusu/PycharmProjects/BlackLineAutomation/main/python/ConnectAPI/first.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

## first.py Contents:

```
from proboscis import test

from proboscis import asserts

@test()
def test1():
    asserts.assert_equal(1, 1)
```

Comment: did you test **assert_equal()** with strings ???

Comment: @ArashHatami, it is definitely not a problem with the assert i am doing. Even if i say,  asserts.assert_equal("1", "1"), i still have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Where are you calling in your function `first.py`? Add edited code is below, which works. 
Have added `Test_Program` code.

```
from proboscis import test
from proboscis import asserts
from proboscis import TestProgram

@test()
def test1():
    asserts.assert_equal(1, 1)

TestProgram().run_and_exit()
```

And the output is :

```
C:\Python\python.exe first.py  
proboscis.case.FunctionTest (test1) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK

Process finished with exit code 0
```